# Relationship between polarization $P$ and displacement field $D$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

In a paper https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.235420, there are following derivation of the relationship. For the free energy, there's an electrostatic energy part, the term is $E_{es}=-(P_s(u)E+1/2(\epsilon(u)-1)E^2)$.
For polarization we have the equation $P=-\partial F(u,E)/(\Omega \partial E)=P_s(u)+(\epsilon(u)-1)\epsilon_0E$. And we have relation $D=\epsilon_0E+P$. $P_s$ is spontaneous polarization without applied field,$\epsilon$ is relative permittivity (they didn't use $\epsilon_r$).u is dimensionless polar internal degree of freedom (atom displacement), in polar is 1 and in non-polar is 0.

Combining above two we can get $P=\dfrac{(\epsilon(u)-1)D+P_s}{\epsilon(u)}$.

It seems contradictory here. For electrostatic and polarization equation above, E should be applied external field because there's a term comes from -PE, while in the second equation E should be the local electric field, either inside the material or in vacuum. So replacing E here should assume P is zero here because it's external E-field not E-field inside material. But the paper did with P term there, meaning substituting $E_{external}$ by $E_{inside}$? I doubt the first substitution there.

Let's take it's true now, and look at the final expression. The paper said 'tune the applied electric displacement field'. Applied field should be in the vacuum so $D_{applied}=\epsilon_0E_{external}$ should be true here. But then it becomes contradictory again: $P=P_s/\epsilon$ at zero electric field is obviously wrong. (In first principles simulations we can only apply electric field, so we need to convert E to D here).

At later part of paper, it says "The energy vs electric
field is perfectly fitted by a quadratic function, confirming
our electrostatic-energy model in Eq. (1)." It seems that in first equation they mean applied field rather than local total field.

[image: Energy variation with aspect to the applied displacement field D/\epsilon_0. The energy of the FE state of the freestanding monolayer is set to be zero]

So where am I wrong? I'm really confused about this.

Comment: Would be nice if you linked the paper, cause what you're saying doesn't make sense. The constitutive relations are always with net local field

Comment: what is the variable $u$?

Comment: the paper is attached and u is atomic displacement, added in main text too.

Comment: If the constitutive relations are always with net local field but in term P*E is always external field, how should the field be then?...